# Нужно сделать чтобы при отправке формы post страница не обновлялась

Tags: php, html, ajax

```html
<div class="lole" >

        Обратная сзязь ,Оставте ваш номер телефона и мы вам перезвоним<br>




    <form method="post"  >
        <br><input type="text" id="form_name" pattern="^[А-Яа-яЁё\s]+${1,17}"  placeholder="Ваше имя" name="name">
        <br><input type="tel" id="form tel"  pattern="[0-9+]{9,11}" placeholder="Ваш номер телефона" name="numb">
        <br><textarea  id="form_zak"  placeholder="Ваш заказ" name="text"></textarea>


       </form>  <input id="go" onclick="senddat();" type="submit" name="go" value="Отправить" />

</div>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function senddat() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "cod.php",
            data: { name: $('#form_name').val(), num:$('#form_tel').val(),text:$('#form_zak').val() },
            success: function(data){$('#res').html(data)}}
        )}

</script>
```

Хочу сделать калькулятор на сайте и на сайте 2 формы уже как мне сделать так чтобы когда я нажимаю на = у меня страница не обновлялась и показывала результат в инете погуглил и там сказано через ajax я вроде как сделать только не

```css
a:active {
  color: black;
}

a:hover {
  color: slategrey;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5%;
  margin-left: 5%;
}

ul {
  background: #f6f9bf;
}

.nav {
  background: #f6f9bf;
  padding-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 1%;
}

.nav a {
  font-size: 2.5vw;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.321s;
}

body {}

html {
  font-family: 'Alegreya Sans', sans-serif;
  ;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

header {
  background: #f6f9bf;
}

body {
  margin: 0px!important;
}

.screen {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url("masina.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s ease-out 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: background 0.3s ease-out 0.2s;
  -o-transition: background 0.3s ease-out 0.2s;
  transition: background 0.3s ease-out 0.2s;
}

.screen:hover {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url("mashina1.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s ease-out 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: background 0.3s ease-out 0.2s;
  -o-transition: background 0.3s ease-out 0.2s;
  transition: background 0.3s ease-out 0.2s;
}

.lol {
  margin-top: 51%;
  text-align: center;
  background: #f6f9bf;
}

.cla {
  border: 10px solid black;
  padding-top: 2%;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
  padding-left: 4%;
  padding-right: 4%;
  left: 2%;
  display: grid;
  width: 30%;
  margin-left: 1%;
  height: 50%;
}

.lep {
  display: flex;
}

.lel {
  border: 10px solid black;
  padding-top: 2%;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
  padding-left: 4%;
  padding-right: 4%;
  left: 2%;
  display: grid;
  width: 30%;
  margin-left: 1%;
  height: 50%;
}

th,
td {
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  padding-left: 0.3vw;
  padding-bottom: 1.5vw;
  font-size: 1.3vw;
}

td,
a {
  -webkit-transition: color 0.321s;
}

.lole {
  margin-right: 60%;
  margin-top: 2200px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding: 3% 3% 3% 3%;
  border: 5px solid black;
  background: #f6f9bf;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 2vw;
}

.lole input,
textarea {
  margin-bottom: 20%;
  padding: 2% 2% 2% 10%;
  background: #f6f9bf;
  font-size: 2vw;
  border: none;
}

.lole input,
textarea:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.lole input,
textarea {
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}

.lole button {
  padding: 10px;
  background: grey;
  outline: none;
  border: 0px;
}

.lole button:active {
  outline: none;
  border: 0px;
  background: dimgrey;
}

.lp {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 1903px;
  height: 80px;
  background: darkgrey;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3500px;
}

.contact {
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 3200px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.lel,
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2vw;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE Html>
<html lang="ru" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="class.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="my_ajax.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#top">ЗАКАЗАТЬ</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#tope">ЦЕНЫ</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#topes">КОНТАКТНЫЕ ДАННЫЕ</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#to">О НАС</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="screen">
  </div>
  <div class="lol">
    <p>
      <a name="to"></a>
    </p>
    <img src="fignya.png" align="center " width="1300px" height="500px">
  </div>
  <div class="lep">
    <div class="lel">
      <a name="tope"></a>
      <h1>Бетон</h1>
      <table cellspacing="0px">
        <tr>
          <td>Марка</td>
          <td>Цена М<sup><small>3</small></sup> </td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>m100</td>
          <td> 3150</td>
          <td><a href="#">Заказать </a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>m150</td>
          <td>3250 </td>
          <td><a href="#">Заказать </a></td>
          <tr>
            <td>m200</td>
            <td>3400 </td>
            <td><a href="#">Заказать </a></td>
            <tr>
              <td>m250</td>
              <td> 3580</td>
              <td><a href="#">Заказать </a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>m300</td>
              <td> 3780</td>
              <td><a href="#">Заказать </a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>m350</td>
              <td> 3950</td>
              <td><a href="#">Заказать </a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>m400</td>
              <td> 4300</td>
              <td><a href="#">Заказать </a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>m450</td>
              <td> 4450</td>
              <td><a href="#">Заказать </a></td>
            </tr>
      </table>
      <a name="top"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="cla">
      <a name="tope"></a>
      <h1>Бетон</h1>
      <table cellspacing="0px">
        <tr>
          <td>Марка</td>
          <td>Цена М<sup><small>3</small></sup> </td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>m100</td>
          <td> 3150</td>
          <td><a href="#">Заказать </a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>m150</td>
          <td>3250 </td>
          <td><a href="#">Заказать </a></td>
          <tr>
            <td>m200</td>
            <td>3400 </td>
            <td><a href="#">Заказать </a></td>
            <tr>
              <td>m250</td>
              <td> 3580</td>
              <td><a href="#">Заказать </a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>m300</td>
              <td> 3780</td>
              <td><a href="#">Заказать </a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>m350</td>
              <td> 3950</td>
              <td><a href="#">Заказать </a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>m400</td>
              <td> 4300</td>
              <td><a href="#">Заказать </a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>m450</td>
              <td> 4450</td>
              <td><a href="#">Заказать </a></td>
            </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>
    <a name="top"></a>
  </p>
  <div class="lole">
    Обратная сзязь ,Оставте ваш номер телефона и мы вам перезвоним<br>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form" id="2">
      <br><input type="text" class="form_name" pattern="^[А-Яа-яЁё\s]+${1,17}" placeholder="Ваше имя" name="name">
      <br><input type="tel" class="form tel" pattern="[0-9+]{9,11}" placeholder="Ваш номер телефона" name="num">
      <br><textarea type="text" class="form zak" placeholder="Ваш заказ" name="text"></textarea>
      <button class="some-form__button" name="but">Отправить</button>
      <?php
        if (isset ($_POST['but']) ) {
            require_once 'sms.ru.php';
            $smsru = new SMSRU('C3A6B841-6B90-4FD6-4ED5-B4FFB841F914'); // Ваш уникальный программный ключ, который можно получить на главной странице
            $name = trim($_POST['name']);
            $num = trim($_POST['num']);
            $text = trim($_POST['text']);

            if(empty($name)){
                echo "Поле имя пусто. ";
                /*Выход или редирект*/
            }

            if(empty($num)){
                echo "Поле номер пусто. ";
                /*Выход или редирект*/
            }

            if(empty($text)){
                echo "Поле заказ  пусто. ";
                /*Выход или редирект*/
            }
            if(!empty($name) && !empty($num) && !empty($text) ){

                $data = new stdClass();
                $data->to = '89065906733';
                $data->text = $name . "-" . $num . "-" . $text; // Текст сообщения

                $sms = $smsru->send_one($data);// Отправка сообщения и возврат данных в переменную
                if ($sms->status == "OK") { // Запрос выполнен успешно
                    echo "Сообщение отправлено успешно. ";
                    echo "Ваш новый баланс: $sms->balance";
                    sleep(5);
                    header("Location: ".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
                } else {
                    echo "Сообщение не отправлено. ";
                    echo "Код ошибки: $sms->status_code. ";
                    echo "Текст ошибки: $sms->status_text.";
                    sleep(5);
                    header("Location: ".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

                }
            }

        }?>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="contact">
    <h1>Контактные данные:</h1>
    <q>89023425523 </q> <q>5zcvxz@mail.ru</q> <q>5xhsxry@gmail.com</q>
    <p>
      <a name="topes"></a>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="calcule">
    <form name="calcul" method="get" method='post' id="calcul">
      <select id="log">
        <option name="mesto" value="700">Архангельское село,Хохольский район</option>
        <option name="mesto" value="1100">Анна</option>
        <option name="mesto" value="370">Александровка</option>
        <option name="mesto" value="400">Бабяково</option>
        <option name="mesto" value="1100">Бобров</option>
        <option name="mesto" value="400">Берёзовка</option>
        <option name="mesto" value="700">Архангельское село,Хохольский район</option>
        <option name="mesto" value="700">Архангельское село,Хохольский район</option>
        <option name="mesto" value="700">Архангельское село,Хохольский район</option>
        <option name="mesto" value="700">Архангельское село,Хохольский район</option>
        <option name="mesto" value="700">Архангельское село,Хохольский район</option>
        <option name="mesto" value="700">Архангельское село,Хохольский район</option>
        <option name="mesto" value="700">Архангельское село,Хохольский район</option>
        <option name="mesto" value="700">Архангельское село,Хохольский район</option>
        <option name="mesto" value="700">Архангельское село,Хохольский район</option>
        <option name="mesto" value="700">Архангельское село,Хохольский район</option>
        <option name="mesto" value="700">Архангельское село,Хохольский район</option>
        <option name="mesto" value="700">Архангельское село,Хохольский район</option>
        <option name="mesto" value="700">Архангельское село,Хохольский район</option>
        <option name="mesto" value="700">Архангельское село,Хохольский район</option>
        <option name="mesto" value="700">Архангельское село,Хохольский район</option>
        <option name="mesto" value="700">Архангельское село,Хохольский район</option>
        <option name="mesto" value="700">Архангельское село,Хохольский район</option>
    </select>
      <input name="num" id="nem" type="number" min="1" step="1">
      <button type="button" onclick="send();" name="sum">=</button>
    </form>
    <div id="respone"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="lp">
    <br><br><br> 2018 Все права защищены. Bet.inc
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Во первых начните со следующего:

1. Перебросьте всю PHP-логику в отдельный файл или же в начале документа (так у нас появится отправная точка и собственно адрес на который мы сможем посылать запрос) (обязательно проверяйте в php входные параметры, если есть $_POST, тогда не показывайте верстку, тем самым вы в ответе не будете передавать ничего лишнего)
2. Уберите слипы (ajax запросы не мгновенные, а останавливать их еще на 5 секунд не есть хорошее решение)
3. Для того что бы не разбираться в XHR, подключите jquery (надеюсь сообщество ругаться не будет)
4. После подключения jquery у вас появится много функций для выполнения конкретно вашей задачи

```js
//Снизу вашей html страницы, после подключения jquery пишем следующее:
$(document).on('ready', function(){
  $.post('адрес вашей страницы', объект с параметрами, function(out){
    console.log(out);
  })
})
```

Comment: тоесть оба обработчика в один файл или в два разных?И можете подробнее объяснить что именно делает ваш код потомучто у меня 2 формы на странице и 3 вопрос если сделать get запросом чтонибудь измееится? потомучто мне нужен простой калькулятор и шифровать данныетдля этого я думаю не обязательно.

Comment: и как мне сделать вывод текста чтобы у меня 1 форма работала как раньше тоесть обычно я просто пишу echo и переменную и текст так вот как мне этот echo вывести если вся логика в другом файле?

Comment: и насчет слипов я их добавил чтобы через 5 сек обновлялась страница и данные post сбрасывались потомучто если обновить страницу то форма заного отправляет данные и если есть вариант как сбросить без редиректа то расскажите пожалуйсто и jQuery у меня есть только не понимаю как его использовать.

Comment: @АлёшаАвилов для начала разбейте ваш калькулятор на 2 файла: 1 - верстка, 2 - php логика, подключите к верстке .js файл, с которым я вам помогу

Comment: Сделал через include в два разных файла и подключил js файл,и ничего что у меня версия jquery 1.10.2 min?

Comment: По идее ничего, я уже не помню чем они друг от друга отличаются) у вас теперь есть 2 адреса физических, один с версткой, второй с пхп логикой, верно?

Comment: верно я уже калькулятор сделал без обновления только форму обратной связи не могу

Comment: @Алёша Авилов, код lazyproger дожидается прогрузки документа(Dom), а затем вызывает собственно post. Я бы лучше использовал $.ajax. Который в ответ принимает все что в обработчике php выведете в echo. $.ajax({ url: 'адрес до обработчика/index.php', method: 'post', data: {Perem: 'Параметр'},  success: function(data){ //здесь обрабатываем ответ  от обработчика} }); И форму лучше очищать собственноручно, а не перезагрузкой. Уберите тег ' form ' и не будет проблем с повторной отправкой формы.

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте. Измените кнопку отправки на такую:

```
<input id="go" onclick="senddat();" type="button" name="go" value="Отправить" />
```

Или на такую:

```
<input id="go" onclick="senddat();return false;" type="submit" name="go" value="Отправить" />
```

Comment: тоесть senddat и в скрипте поставить?

Comment: @АлёшаАвилов это во первом коде, во втором нужно добавить `type="button`. Вот так: `<button type="button" class="some-form__button" name="but">Отправить</button>`

Comment: @АлёшаАвилов или чтобы вообще форма не отправлялась можно сделать так `<form onsubmit="return false;">...</form>`

Answer (score 0):

Вставлю свои пару копеек:

- Отправляя через ajax/fetch и т.д. `form` можно вообще убрать.
- у кнопки замените `type="submit"` на `type="button"` именно это и перезагружает вашу страницу.
- **Отвыкайте привязывать события непосредственно в самом элементе.** Использование в коде `onclick=` это уже моветон. Отслеживать события надо со стороны скрипта jquery/js